# Ruby ransack filter options dependent on result

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ransack, ancestry

I am using ransack to search and filter results of a listing application. One filter is narrowing down the search by category (which uses ancestry) and the other one narrows it down for location (saved inside the listings table).

So far they work separately, meaning I can't filter both attributes together.

What I want to do know is that the filter "are talking" to each other. That means if I select a category the location filter should only show locations where there is actually a result for category and location together. Makes sense?
How can I achieve that inside the controller?

My current regular search which works:

```
if params[:category]
   @category = Category.find_by_slug(params[:category])
   @search = Listing.search(country_cont: params[:country], state_cont: params[:state], city_cont: params[:city], category_id_in: @category.subtree_ids)
else
     @search = Listing.search(country_cont: params[:country], state_cont: params[:state], city_cont: params[:city])
end
```

I tried something like this:

```
@category_filter = Listing.search(country_cont: params[:country], state_cont: params[:state], city_cont: params[:city])
@country_filter = Listing.search(country_cont: params[:country], state_cont: params[:state], city_cont: params[:city], category_id_in: @category.subtree_ids)
@category_dropdown = @category_filter.result
@country_dropdown = @country_filter.result
```

and then using the result to populate the dropdown. 
Somebody has a neat trick for that?